# Rpi -3 fail to run `esptool`

Tags: python, software-installation, cross-compilation

In order to communicate with ESP32 to run miropython code, I needed to install `esptool` on my RPI ( done successfully )- using this [guide](https://www.rototron.info/raspberry-pi-esp32-micropython-tutorial/)
.

When executing, I got an error message that it doesnot exit-

`esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 flash_id`

Comment: What command do you use to execute?

Comment: you are right, added to Q

Comment: What is the output of _dmesg | grep ttyUSB_

Comment: my bet is that you got a message saying _/dev/ttyUSB0 : No such file exist_

Comment: file exists ...

Comment: What is the error message you are getting ?